# Cancan custom action won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have this rule:

```
can :see_contacts, Profile do |profile|
  false
end
```

And this check:

```
- if can? :see_contacts, @profile
   # user contacts
```

The problem is, that I always see user contacts. Why?

Comment: You should be able to put a log statement in that block to see if it gets called at all.

Comment: Try `- if can? :see_contacts, Profile` instead. I've found cancan slightly buggy/inconsistent when working with instances vs classes.

Comment: No, profile is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh, always read the documentation. This is my case.

**Important notice about :manage.** As you read above it represents ANY action on the object. So if you have something like:

```
can :manage, User
can :invite, User
```

and if you take a test of last :invite rule you always get true. Why? That's because :manage represents ANY action on object and :manage is not just :create, :read, :update, :destroy on object.